# differences between `top` and `system-monitor`

Tags: gnome, top, cpu-usage

I noticed a difference in CPU percentage between two utility:
`top` and `gnome-sytem-monitor` (but the same happens with `htop`...)

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVPEp.png) shows the issue.

You can see as first item both is the process `gnome-shell` but on the left, `top` shows/measures a 70% while on the right `gnome-system-monitor` shows 16%, that's a huge difference.

Why? Is it a bug or simply a different method of measures?

---

[image]

---

Comment: What is value of `update interval in seconds` under `preferences->processes->Behavior` section?

Comment: @saisasanka it's 1 second

Comment: So try seeing if the results, by modifying delay of the `top` command.

Comment: No, it (`top -d 1`) doesn't work; nothing changes...

Comment: Does Nothing changes mean , you still see the behavior mentioned in the question? But I see a clear difference in my system, seeing both side-by-side after changing refresh time for both `top` and `gnmoe-system-monitor` .  Also enable `CPU Time` in `gnome-system-monitor` tool to get an idea of time at which stat is being collected. This field is displayed by default in `top`. Perhaps you could also sort the data displayed in descending order of `%cpu` in both the tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue solved!

[image]

`top` shows **per-core** CPU usage, thus the sum of percentage will be greater than 100.

While `gnome-system-monitor` is able to show both **per-core** and **per-CPU**.
Indeed there is an option (underlined in the screenshot above) that can switch the behaviour.

---

Systems (usually) have 1 CPU with multiple cores.
In my case, I have 1 CPU with 4 cores. The screenshot shows a CPU stress utility (`stress`) running on just one core -- one core busy. As you can see, `top` shows the`stress` process at 100% and other processes, that is sum will be greater than 100. On the other hand `gnome-system-monitor` *with the underlined option enabled*, shows the same `stress` process at 25% (exactly one forth of `top` usage).

Answer (score 1):

I see not much differences between these two commands. Both `top and gnome-sytem-monitor` give `per core %cpu utilization. (Here % can be greater than 100)` The difference that you see can be attributed to the  time interval at which both these commands are collecting the stats.

So please change `update interval in seconds` under `preferences->processes->Behavior` section to `1.00` in `gnome-sytem-monitor`.

Also do the same for `top` because by default it refreshes every `3.00 seconds`. Hit the `top -p <pid>` command and press `d` to set the `Change delay from 3.00 to: 1.00s` and hit enter. Now I don't see much difference at all.

[image]
You can see the same in the screenshot above. [ Observe that even now there might be a difference in `%cpu` stat because of difference in `seconds` part of time at which the utility is collecting the stat ]